# R: How to delete multiple columns in a nested list matching by string pattern

Tags: r, list

I´m having this kind of dataset in a list:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Col_1 = c(0,0,0,0,0),
                  Col_2 = c(1,1,1,1,1),
                  Col_3 = c("text", "text", "text", "text", "text"),
                  test = c(0,0,0,0,0))

df2 <- data.frame(Col_1 = c(0,0,0,0,0),
                  Col_2 = c(1,1,1,1,1),
                  Col_3 = c(2,2,2,2,2),
                  ab...c = c(0,0,0,0,0))
l <- list(df1, df2)
```

How can I delete all the columns in the list, which contain for example a string pattern like `'...'` or `'test'` in it´s name?

I my mind I would imagine something like the `contains()` or `matches()` function combinded with the `dplyr::select` function
`dplyr::select(l, -contains(c("...", "text")))` but I can´t get the code running with lists.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `map`

```r
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- data.frame(Col_1 = c(0,0,0,0,0),
                  Col_2 = c(1,1,1,1,1),
                  Col_3 = c("text", "text", "text", "text", "text"),
                  test = c(0,0,0,0,0))

df2 <- data.frame(Col_1 = c(0,0,0,0,0),
                  Col_2 = c(1,1,1,1,1),
                  Col_3 = c(2,2,2,2,2),
                  ab...c = c(0,0,0,0,0))
l <- list(df1, df2) 

map(l, ~ select(.x, -contains(c("...", "text"))))
#> [[1]]
#>   Col_1 Col_2 Col_3 test
#> 1     0     1  text    0
#> 2     0     1  text    0
#> 3     0     1  text    0
#> 4     0     1  text    0
#> 5     0     1  text    0
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   Col_1 Col_2 Col_3
#> 1     0     1     2
#> 2     0     1     2
#> 3     0     1     2
#> 4     0     1     2
#> 5     0     1     2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>